# Using regex to replace a certain string - Java

Tags: java, regex

My goal is to replace a certain substring within a string that doesn't alter those that aren't strictly that substring. It is slightly confusing to write down so let me show you with an example.

Say I have the string

```
"StackOverflow Stack Overflow Stacks"
```

Now I would like to replace `"Stack"`, if I am to use

```
x.replaceAll("Stack", "")
```

I will get

```
"Overflow  Overflow s"
```

which is not desired, instead I would like the following:

```
"StackOverflow Overflow Stacks"
```

Comment: There are a lot of good regex tutorials and examples in the net, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
\\bStack\\b
```

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is not entirely clear.

You need to think about the conditions for `"Stack"` to be replaced.

A good example would be a word boundary: `x.replaceAll("\\bStack\\b", "")`

This will ensure that `"Stack"` surrounded by non-word characters will be replaced, while other instances of `"Stack"` will be left untouched.

You may want to be more specific and only replace when surrounded by whitespace:

- `x.replaceAll("(?<=\\s)Stack(?=\\s)", "") // replaces only "Stack"`
- `x.replaceAll("\\sStack\\s", "") // also gets rid of the surrounding whitespace`

Etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can use word boundaries to accomplish this:

use the below code for the same:

```
String abc = "StackOverflow Stack Overflow Stacks";
abc = abc.replaceAll("\\bStack\\b", "");

System.out.println(abc);
```

The result is printed as **StackOverflow  Overflow Stacks**